# (Jquery Validate Plugin) How can be 1 of the form fields validate with ajax call and the rest fields with client validation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How can be 1 of the form fields validate with ajax call and the rest fields with client validation?
(I use Jquery + Jquery validate plugin  http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

The case:

**register.html**

```
<form id="register" name="register">
firstname<input id="username" name="username"/>
user<input id="user" name="user"/>
phone<input id="phone" name="phone"/>
</form>

<script src="../lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
$('#register').validate(
{
rules: {
        firstname: "required",
        phone: "required"
  }
});
```

**user_exist.php**:

```
if ( userExist($_REQUEST['user']){
  echo 'success';
}
else{
  echo 'please choose another user'
}
```

I know how validate only firstname and phone, but username that should be validate by server before submit I don't.

Please help me to do serveer ajax validation for user field.
(I simplify the code)
Thanks

Comment: IMO doing a separate call for validation is horribly inefficient. Simply submit the form via AJAX and return errors and handle them like failed validation (depending on the error of course). However, this doesn't apply for forms containing upload fields.. in that case a separate validation request makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's an exact example in the demo pages:
http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/

```
username: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2,
    remote: "users.php"
},
```

Just remember to `echo "true";` on success in your server side

Comment: Thanks! 1. how can be server message display a failure 2. I try to see server code of your example but its not working for me (Ubuntu firefox)

Comment: @Yose: check the source of the link I posted to check how to handle remote messages, as for the second point, it's just an example but [here's](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/users.phps) the file anyway.

Comment: Thanks you vaery much! still I only success to get true/false message from server

Comment: @Yose: of course! otherwise the plugin will not validate the field! why do you need to send the messages *from* the server?!